# gatsby react-spring-3d issue

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Does anyone know how to fix this issue Gatsby with react-spring-3d-carousel:

import Carousel from "react-spring-3d-carousel"

and

```
<Carousel slides={slides} goToSlide={selectedSlide} />.
```

I looked in the docs but still appears error: window is not defined

gatsby-node.js

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /react-spring-3d-carousel/,
              use: loaders.null(),
            },
          ],
        },
      })
    }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When the `window` not defined appears? `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`?

Comment: Have you looked at this issue? https://github.com/gutiguy/react-spring-3d-carousel/issues/8

Comment: @FerranBuireu gatsby develop, but I fixed with @loadable/component.
these 2 lines fixed my issue.
import loadable from "@loadable/component";
const Carousel = loadable(() => import("react-spring-3d-carousel"))

Thank you again :)

Comment: @Josh thanks, I just find my issue and fixed with @loadable/component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others that may be facing similar issues, not only related to `react-spring-3d-carousel`: if adding a `null` loader to the SSR transpilation doesn't work, the other possible workaround is adding a loadable component, which in fact, what is doing is to perform a code-splitting in the server-side.

```
import loadable from "@loadable/component"; 
const Carousel = loadable(() => import("react-spring-3d-carousel"))
```